# regex: how to select first, second, third match

Tags: regex, metabase

Sorry I am quite new with regex.
I have items like:

```
"Cafes", "Footwear", "Women's fashion"
```

I can select the 3 items: `/".+?"/`

The first item only : `/^".+?"/`

But what about the second, third item?
What is the best way to match them?

Is there a generic way to select nth match in regex?

Many Thanks !

D

Comment: Please specify the language/application/framework you're using

Comment: This is important because not all regex engines support the features you need in order to solve this entirely in regex. However, it might be worth thinking about whether there is another way to do this, for example by using the simple regex `/".+?"/g` (assuming JavaScript) to match all three at once, accessing the single matches programmatically. Also, you'll run into problems if there can be escaped quotes within strings, unbalanced quotes or linebreaks in your strings etc. - you need to know and specify all the constraints your data could be under in order to build a "reasonable" regex

Comment: Thanks for your replies !
I am using the regexp engine inside Metabase. 
I cannot use a programmatic way to manipulate the matches (as far as I know). 
The strings are coming from a multiple choice typeform answer, so I am not worried about escape and other quirks, they are plain words (inside"")

Comment: Another way to put this question: 
I want the match between nth and nth+1 occurence of " :  i.e. n=3 gives me Footwear in "Cafes", "Footwear", "Women's fashion"

Comment: I don't know Metabase and its regex flavor, but if it support non-fixed width lookbehind, [`(?<=^(?:"[^"]*", ){1})"[^"]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/tdlqvb/1) might work. The PCRE equivalent of that would be [`^(?:"[^"]*", ){1}\K"[^"]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/tdlqvb/2).

Comment: Thanks @InSync - that's the answer that works for me. You may write it as an answer and I can tick it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I'm unsure about Metabase's regex flavor. However, if it supports non-fixed-width lookbehind, you can use:

```
(?<=                # Match something preceded by
  ^                 # the start of string
  (?:               # then
    "[^"]*",\x20    # a quoted string followed by a comma and a space
  ){n}              # n time
)                   # 
"[^"]*"             # where "something" is a quoted string.
```

*n* can be 0 or any positive integer. The element matched will have an 1-based index of *n + 1*.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tdlqvb/1).

In the case Metabase doesn't support that, you can also try your luck on PCRE's `\K`:

```
^                   # Match at the start of string
(?:"[^"]*", ){n}    # n elements with commas
\K                  # then forfeit everything we just matched
"[^"]*"             # before matching a quoted string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tdlqvb/2).